# Database log file is so big

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log, recovery-model

My database log file is so big(400 giga) and data file is (50 giga)
My recovery method is simple and backup plan is daily full backup
Log file is configured to auto growth.
I checked open transactions, this the output
[image]
I tried to solve it but I can't.
Thank you

Comment: What does the query `SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'YourDatabaseName'` show?

Comment: Do you have [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) enabled?

Comment: @J.D. 'REPLICATION'

Comment: @HannahVernon no, it's disabled

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMamdouh are you using Availability Groups or Replication?

Comment: @J.D. no, it's single node without any replication